# How to extract from dataframe by mapping to multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df`

```
Sample  CHROM   POS        REF  ALT
003C    chr1    248650751   T   A
003P1   chr1    248650751   T   A
003P2   chr1    248650751   T   A
003C    chr18   48399       C   A
003P1   chr20   145653      G   T
003P1   chr8    244695      C   A
003C    chr11   5986513     G   A
003P1   chr8    244695      C   A
003P2   chr11   5986513     G   A
003P1   chr11   5986513     G   A
004C    chr11   1163940     C   G
004P1   chr11   1163940     C   G
004P2   chr11   1163940     C   G
```

I want to extract a dataframe that matches `'CHROM' 'POS' 'REF' 'ALT'` for `Sample`
output will look like:

```
Sample  CHROM   POS        REF  ALT
003C    chr1    248650751   T   A
003P1   chr1    248650751   T   A
003P2   chr1    248650751   T   A
003C    chr11   5986513     G   A
003P2   chr11   5986513     G   A
003P1   chr11   5986513     G   A
004C    chr11   1163940     C   G
004P1   chr11   1163940     C   G
004P2   chr11   1163940     C   G
```

`Sample` may not be in order. C, P1, P2 make a set with their number in the begining. `003C, 003P1, 003P2` is a set where I need to check common columns. I tried using `pivot` but it doesnot work. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible filter exactly 3 rows per groups by all columns without first use:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['CHROM', 'POS', 'REF', 'ALT'])['POS'].transform('size').eq(3)]

print (df)
   Sample  CHROM        POS REF ALT
0    003C   chr1  248650751   T   A
1   003P1   chr1  248650751   T   A
2   003P2   chr1  248650751   T   A
6    003C  chr11    5986513   G   A
8   003P2  chr11    5986513   G   A
9   003P1  chr11    5986513   G   A
10   004C  chr11    1163940   C   G
11  004P1  chr11    1163940   C   G
12  004P2  chr11    1163940   C   G
```

Here is more complicated filtering - first are exctracted numbers in `Sample` and all another values:

```
df[['a','b']] = df['Sample'].str.extract('(\d+)(.*)')
print (df)
   Sample  CHROM        POS REF ALT    a   b
0    003C   chr1  248650751   T   A  003   C
1   003P1   chr1  248650751   T   A  003  P1
2   003P2   chr1  248650751   T   A  003  P2
3    003C  chr18      48399   C   A  003   C
4   003P1  chr20     145653   G   T  003  P1
5   003P1   chr8     244695   C   A  003  P1
6    003C  chr11    5986513   G   A  003   C
7   003P1   chr8     244695   C   A  003  P1
8   003P2  chr11    5986513   G   A  003  P2
9   003P1  chr11    5986513   G   A  003  P1
10   004C  chr11    1163940   C   G  004   C
11  004P1  chr11    1163940   C   G  004  P1
12  004P2  chr11    1163940   C   G  004  P2
```

And then filter size 3 groups by `m1`, then if number of unique value is `3` by `m2` and last if exist all 3 values `['C','P1','P2']` there per groups:

```
g = df.groupby(['CHROM', 'POS', 'REF', 'ALT', 'a'])['b']
m1 = g.transform('size').eq(3)
m2 = g.transform('nunique').eq(3)
m3 = g.transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(['C','P1','P2']))
df = df[m1 & m2 & m3]
print (df)
   Sample  CHROM        POS REF ALT    a   b
0    003C   chr1  248650751   T   A  003   C
1   003P1   chr1  248650751   T   A  003  P1
2   003P2   chr1  248650751   T   A  003  P2
6    003C  chr11    5986513   G   A  003   C
8   003P2  chr11    5986513   G   A  003  P2
9   003P1  chr11    5986513   G   A  003  P1
10   004C  chr11    1163940   C   G  004   C
11  004P1  chr11    1163940   C   G  004  P1
12  004P2  chr11    1163940   C   G  004  P2
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not taking care of `Sample`. It extracts when `Sample` is different.

Comment: So need like second soluto and test if only one `C`, `P1`, `P2` per groups?